# Material UI DatePicker doesn't display updated time in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, material-ui, datetime-format

I'm using Material UI KeyboardDatePicker for my app, and when I select a date and console.log it at first select date & time are displayed correctly, but if I wait 1-2 minutes and select another date, date will be updated but time will be the same as 1st select. For example, if I select March 26th, date will be displayed as  Friday Mar 24 2021 17:49:00 GMT-0400, if I wait 2 minutes and select March 27th, date will be Saturday Mar 24 2021 but time still 17:49:00 GMT-0400 ( although actual time is 17:51:00). My code is:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from "@material-ui/pickers";
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";


import { KeyboardDatePicker } from "@material-ui/pickers";



export default function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const [date, setDate] = useState();

  const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    setDate(date);
  };

  console.log(date)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
          <KeyboardDatePicker
            style={{ width: 200, height: 28 }}
            minDate={new Date()}
            disableToolbar={true}
            margin="none"
            variant="inline"
            value={date}
            inputVariant="outlined"
            emptyLabel="Select Date"
            format="MM/dd/yyyy"
            onChange={handleDateChange}
            KeyboardButtonProps={{
              onFocus: (e) => {
                setIsOpen(true);
              }
            }}
            PopoverProps={{
              disableRestoreFocus: true,
              onClose: () => {
                setIsOpen(false);
              }
            }}
            InputProps={{
              onFocus: () => {
                setIsOpen(true);
              }
            }}
            open={isOpen}
          />
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-vaughan-c94qd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

I don't know why time doesn't update each time I select another date. Any help and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the component has a unique Date object that is instantiated once. Upon a new day selection, it would manually update year, month and day, preserving the rest of the properties.

You can manually update the hours, minutes and seconds on the change handler

```
const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    const updatedDate = new Date();
    date.setHours(updatedDate.getHours());
    date.setMinutes(updatedDate.getMinutes());
    date.setSeconds(updatedDate.getSeconds());
    setDate(date);
  };
```

[working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-drake-u4w9r?file=/src/App.js:356-589)